# Why isn't this y/n loop working?

Tags: c++, loops, logic, boolean-logic

So I'm making a look that asks if you would like to level up your character. If you say yes it asks you again until you're level 20 (the D&D level cap) or until you say no.

I type y then hit enter, it says it's wrong, hit n then enter, same thing. Here's my code:

```
char yn;
do {
    cin >> yn;
    while (yn != 'y' || yn != 'n') {
        cout << "Only y or n are valid options, try again: ";
        cin >> yn;
    }
    if (yn == 'y')
        f.levelUp();
    cout << endl;
} while(yn != 'n' || f.getLevel() != 20);
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (yn != 'y' || yn != 'n')
```

should be

```
while (yn != 'y' && yn != 'n')
```

Since it's only invalid if the input is NOT `'y'` **AND** it's NOT `'n'`.

Same goes for the outer loop when you're checking for not `'n'` AND not yet level 20, otherwise you can only exit that loop if you enter `'n'` and you're at level 20.

Comment: Did both of these and all is well, now I just have to fix some stat related bugs!

Answer (score 7):

Make your || an &&. Think about it; yn can't be both 'y' and 'n', so that condition is always true.

Comment: Just fixed it, it should be done for the n/level check at the end.